# Is OBD-II a universal standard?

Tags: obd-ii

I'm following this guide: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-fix-your-check-engine-light/?ALLSTEPS

According to this website an OBD-II reader will work with my 53 Vauxall Zafira, but I want to be sure they are a universal standard. Will any reader do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, OBD-II is an international standard that (almost) all car manufacturers use for vehicle diagnostics. Your car will have an OBD-II port on it somewhere for connecting an adapter to.

See [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/322/what-are-good-features-to-look-for-in-an-odb-ii-reader?rq=1) for what to look for in an adapter.